# How to create a git repository in network folder with smbcliente?

Tags: linux, git

How can I create a git repository in network folder?

Where I have use `smbclient` command to acess this folder from my linux sever

Comment: Are you unable to use `git` commands?

Comment: I can use, but probleme is create a git repo in this folder with `smbclient`

Comment: Why use `smbclient` when it isn't git? If you're able to use them I would recommend you do.

Comment: Because I have use `smbclient` to use this folder

Comment: Consider creating the repo locally and then copying it to the server using the smbclient?